# Converting matrix elements into character in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, cell-array

I'm working on matrices at the moment and i created a simple example where:

```
my_mat = [10 5 6; 2 4 8; 1 20 50]
```

and what I'm trying to do now is to sort the elements in the matrix in lexicographical order.

I tried using the sortrows function in matlab:

```
sortrows(my_mat)
```

which outputs:

```
1    20   50
2     4    8
10    5    6
```

But then i realize if i do it in the form of cell array:

```
my_cell_array = {10 5 6; 2 4 8; 1 20 50}
```

and converting each number to character:

```
str_array = cellfun(@num2str,my_cell_array,'UniformOutput',false)
```

which gives:

```
'10'   '5'   '6'
'2'    '4'   '8'
'1'    '20'  '50'
```

and

```
sortrows(str_array)
```

gives:

```
'1'    '20'   '50'
'10'   '5'    '6'
'2'    '4'    '8'
```

which is lexicographic ordering. Apparently i learnt that sortrows() will sort numbers lexicographically only when they're represented as characters. Is there any ways to convert the **numbers** in **my_mat** to **characters** similar to that of the **cell array**?

Comment: `s = cellstr(string(sortrows(x)))` with x being your matrice, or simply `s = string(sortrows(x))` if you can deal with a string array.

Comment: You should add the expected output to your question. I'm not sure how lexicographic order is defined for 2d structures (like numeric arrays) - do you want to sort elements in each row? column? output a vector with sorted values?

Answer (score 0):

```
my_mat = [10 5 6; 2 4 8; 1 20 50]
mat_sort = sortrows(my_mat)
mat_cell = num2cell(mat_sort)
mat_str_sort = cellfun(@num2str,mat_cell,'UniformOutput',false)
```

just convert your sorted matrix to cell of character

Comment: thanks but i think sortrows() should come last to sort lexicographical order?